# Overfull \hbox problem in Algorithm caption of ACM template

Tags: pdftex, errors, boxes, algorithms, algorithm2e

I faced  a problem that my overleaf report that 'Overfull \hbox (8.5pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 92--92'
I used 'algorithm2e' package for ACM template.
Here is the test demo I used:

```
\documentclass[wcp]{jmlr}
% The following packages will be automatically loaded:
% amsmath, amssymb, natbib, graphicx, url, algorithm2e
\usepackage{longtable}% for long tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htb!]
\caption{...}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwIn{ABBA}
\KwOut{BABA}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

And the result show:
[image]
[image]
What should I do to modify this strange format?

Comment: your example gives the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`

Comment: If I add `\begin{document}...\end{document}` it runs with no overfull hbox. Please fix the question to have an example of the problem

Comment: Sorry for that. But when I fixed the problem, the output is still in same. still warning 'Overfull \hbox (8.5pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--10'

Comment: I edited the problem description and upload a full screenshot after fixing the error. Maybe it can be clearer.

Comment: do you get an overfull box warning from the posted code if so please  show your log. I get no overfull box so would not be able to guess your issue

Comment: I added it in the description.